# How are weights treated in the cluster_walktrap function in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, modularity

I am working with character networks of plays. Nodes represent characters, edges represent speeches they address to one another. It is a directed network, and the edge weights are equal to the number of words the source character says to the target.

In iGraph, edge weight sometimes means distance, and sometimes means closeness. To get the correct results for `betweenness`, for instance, I need to invert the edge weights so the more words a character says to another, the 'closer' they are in the network:

```
edgeData <- data.frame(source, target, weight = numWords)
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edgeData)
betweenness(graph, weights = 1/E(graph)$weight)
```

Now I want to study the community structure of my plays, and I don't know how to use the algorithms correctly. Should I treat edge weights as distances, and invert the weights so characters who talk more are 'closer' to one another?

```
cluster_walktrap(graph, weights = 1/E(graph)$weight)
```

Or should I treat the weights as, well, weights, and use the algorithm in its default state?

```
cluster_walktrap(graph)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cluster_walktrap(graph)`is OK. Community detection, weight is weight, not distance.

I am also confused when I calculate some graph indices.

but if you want to calculate shortest path (or other ), you should use 
`weights = 1/E(graph)$weight`

you can design a demo.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.